# Devise - Getting 401 when hitting /signup route via curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a pretty vanilla rails API with devise configured.

I get a 401 `{"error":"Invalid Email or password."}` when I try and sign up a new user via curl however /login works fine.

`curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d ' {"user":{"email":"test2@test.com","password":"test12345"}}' http://localhost:3000/signup`

However works fine when I run from rails console:

`User.create! email: "test5@test.com", password: "test12345"`

Here are my routes:

```
devise_for :users,
               path: '',
               path_names: {
                 registration: 'signup',
                 sign_in: 'login',
                 sign_out: 'logout'
               },
               controllers: {
                 registrations: 'registrations',
                 sessions: 'sessions'
               }
```

How can I get rails to give me a more verbose debugging messages? I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Have you tried including the password_confirmation parameter as well?

Comment: Yep it does the same thing

Comment: Since you have a custom registrations controller you can just add a breakpoint inside of `Registrations#create` with `super { |resource| binding.pry }` or `super { |resource| byebug }`. All the devise controller actions yield the resource (the user) being CRUD:ed.

Comment: You should also replace cURL with a actual integration test/spec.

Comment: Yup I have a integration test

Comment: Please post RegistrationsController and exact devise/rails versions

Comment: Doesn't rails server output show the log? You can check out development.log if not.
Regarding the issue, you are probably just being redirected after the sign up by Device's after_sign_up_path_for callback.

Comment: It just says 401 and it doesn't reach my controller

Comment: Do you have the `rack-cors` gem installed and configured?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are hitting the csrf protection and that you have added some global error handler. https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf

The application thinks that you are malicious :D

The idea is that if you login to the site, you'll get a cookie and so on. If someone tricks you to make a requests from some other site (e.g. fake popup for notifications or an ad where you just click X to close it).

Usually they can just redirect you but still you are fully logged in as you have a session cookie, so.. if by mistake you perform some destructive action on GET, they can trigger that as many times as they want.

To prevent this all the forms have a csrf token when rendered. So when you submit the form the token is also submitted and verified on the server.

When you trigger the curl command you are not passing the csrf token.

When you go to http://localhost:3000/signup/sign_up, and inspect the form you'll see the token at the top e.g.

```
<form class="new_user" id="new_user" action="/signup" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="ZrhdZbibdKzygUem67VxNrTmT5jOU/GTxgqYz3+rtErAdEKBKUrk2zMD0vu3qTh1jmlLVhlnfbYyH7/FZpKuqA==">
....
</form>
```

The csrf token is also in the head of the html.

So.. if you want to call the controller with curl you have to pass that token:

```
$ curl --cookie-jar my-cookie http://localhost:3000/signup/sign_up  | grep csrf-token
<meta name="csrf-token" content="iVjcWccB8tO+ywG+CM9RD2NJQ4CkPjeyoYb9F6U0XUajabq8ZSHRoeoT1hAgxwKsqKDYP3gf4CHR6GjODLbt3w==" />

$ curl --cookie my-cookie  -H "Content-type: application/json" --data-binary '{"authenticity_token": "iVjcWccB8tO+ywG+CM9RD2NJQ4CkPjeyoYb9F6U0XUajabq8ZSHRoeoT1hAgxwKsqKDYP3gf4CHR6GjODLbt3w==","user":{"email":"test1@test.com","password":"test12345","password_confirmation":"test12345"}}' localhost:3000/signup
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:3000/">redirected</a>.</body></html>* Closing connection 0
```

This overall creates the user if you really start cleanly:

```
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise User
# and you add the top part of the routing before the custom controllers
```

---

Another amazing option is that you may have disabled the csrf protection and somehow you are hitting the login page :D  / you have messed up with the custom RegistrationsController / SessionsController

---

In the tab where you run the application, you can see log printed on stdout and you'll see what is happening and which endpoint is answering.